# Font size in px differs between platforms

Tags: css, font-size

I am a utter beginner with css and sending html/css mails from FileMaker (database). I have read http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/units.en.html on font sizing. I would like to be able to set a standard font size for the mails, and use px for that, as it should be an absolute size. If I send mail from Windows to Windows, or from Mac to Mac, the size stays the same, but on Mac 1 px seems to be 1 pt (1/72 inch), while on Windows it is 1/96 inch. 
The html looks like:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type='text/css'>
body
{
font-family: 'Arial';
font-size: 14px;
font-style: normal;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<SPAN STYLE= "" ><BR><BR>text</SPAN>
</body>
</html>
```

Sending mail from Mac to Windows results in a smaller font, from Windows to Mac in a bigger font. What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I would use **em** instead of px if you want a slightly more consistent size.

If you want to get *fancy* you could use the new fangled **rem** unit. It doesn't work in all the browsers but its a responsive variation, resizing depnding on the user's specific resolution and ppi settings.